# Foreign key from a NON audit trail table to an audit trail table

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-schema

In an existing schema I am introducing audit trail/milestone support only for one of the tables. For discussing the question we'll use following simplified toy example for better illustration of a question.

```
DEPARTMENT
ID   |  NAME  | CREATED_TS | MODIFIED_TS | VERSION
1    | "ABC"  | 11/20/2015 | 12/1/9999   | 1
```

Now when every time update request for `department` record for id=1 comes in, system does following. Basically each update is an `INSERT` - which changes existing record's `MODIFIED_TS` to the time `UPDATE` request came in and latest record's `MODIFIED_TS` always remains as `12/1/9999` (a.k.a `INFINITY` TIMESTAMP)

Say updating ID=1 record where name was changed , following is what it looks like in db.

```
DEPARTMENT
ID   |  NAME  | CREATED_TS | MODIFIED_TS  | VERSION
1    | "ABC"  | 11/20/2015 | 11/22/2015   | 1
1    | "XYZ"  | 11/22/2015 | 12/1/9999    | 2
```

Now assume there is an existing `EMPLOYEE` table with `DEPT_ID` as a foreign key. Note that `EMPLOYEE` table doesn't have an audit trail requirement so there is no `INFINITY` timestamp or `VERSION`ing concept there. `EMPLOYEE` table looks like as below

```
EMPLOYEE
ID | NAME    | AGE | DEPT_ID
1  | "John"  | 31  | 1
```

Everything was fine in terms of EMPLOYEE having a FK relationship with DEPT where DEPT had ID as a PK before. Now `DEPARTMENT` table's PK is changed to a composite PK (ID,VERSION)

After these schema changes for `DEPARTMENT` table to create auit trail for its data, FK in `EMPLOYEE` will have to somehow create a FK in such a way where not only `DEPT_ID` but also include `INFINITY` timestamp (`MODIFIED_TS` ) of `DEPT` record into it because `EMPLOYEE` will always be referring the latest `DEPT` record (requirement)

What's the best way to change `EMPLOYEE` table's FK for pointing to the most current record in `DEPT` table?

Comment: I think that there are better ways of tracking changes to the department table.  Specifically, store old values in a separate table.  Then you don't have to do anything to the employee table.

Comment: Why are you storing the audit data in the Department table?

Answer (score 0):

This is a **terrible** data-modelling hack to *solve* your problem; don't try this at home...

Since the PK for department is {id, modified_ts}, the FK from employee must also be composite (or it could point to another unique set of columns).
So the solution is to give it what it wants: a column with a constant value of 'infinity'. ('infinity' is a valid value for dates and timestamps in postgres, you don't need to invent your own sentinel values)

```
CREATE TABLE department
        ( id INTEGER NOT NULL
        , name varchar
        , created_ts timestamp
        , modified_ts timestamp
        , version integer not null default 0
        , PRIMARY KEY (id, modified_ts)
        );

INSERT INTO department (id, name, created_ts, modified_ts, version) VALUES
 (1  , 'ABC', '2015-11-20' , '2015-11-22' , 1) ,
 (1  , 'XYZ', '2015-11-22' , 'infinity'  , 2) ;

-- CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON department (id) WHERE modified_ts = 'infinity'::timestamp;

-- Now assume there is an existing EMPLOYEE table with DEPT_ID as a foreign key. Note that EMPLOYEE table doesn't have an audit trail requirement so there is no INFINITY timestamp or VERSIONing concept there. EMPLOYEE table looks like as below

CREATE TABLE employee
        ( id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , name varchar
        , age  integer not null default 0
        , modified_ts timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT 'infinity'::timestamp CHECK (modified_ts = 'infinity'::timestamp)
        , dept_id INTEGER NOT NULL
        , FOREIGN KEY (id,modified_ts)
                REFERENCES department(id, modified_ts)
        );
INSERT INTO employee(id ,name,age,dept_id) VALUES
(1  , 'John'  , 31  , 1);
```

---

- a FK really **SHOULD NOT** point to a *moving target*
- for the above to work, the FK constraint will need `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED`
- but in practice you should use *stable* keys, (and move the trail to a separate table)
- and in real life, *both* employee and department should allow history, and so should their (M:N) junction table.